# Does a paint app on an android phone require an xml layout?

Tags: java, android, xml

Do i need a layout for a view for when the user "paints" on the screen? And what type of layout should i have? Can it be virtually anything? Like a white screen? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use at least one layout which will act as your holder View.

It can be a white screen or whatever you want etc.Instead of programming creating all the views make a holder View for your paint stuff and do the painting on it.

Comment: So i can have any color screen and have the java call the layout?

Comment: Yes you can have any color or whatever you want and call the View programmatically in your Java code.

Answer (score 1):

No, XML layouts are optional. You can create it programmatically:

```
View view = new MyCustomPaintView(context);
setContentView(view);
```

But XML layouts are very usefull (**and strictly recommended**) when you need to place many Views on a screen.